# How to automatize the headers needed to make a get request?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

I'm currently working on a web scrapping project and the way that I'm doing it is with a mixture of Selenium and requests using Python. I'm scrapping the airline LATAM (a chilean airline) making API calls. In order to get the endpoints and all that stuff is manually using the Google Chrome Web Inspector. Now, for some requests that I need to do, I need some cookies that I cannot get with the requests python library. Let me ilustrate you with an example:

```python
def cookies_to_string(cookie_jar):
    i = 0
    string_cookies = ""
    for cookie in cookie_jar:
        if i == len(cookie_jar)-1:
            string_cookies += cookie.name + "=" + cookie.value
        else:
            string_cookies += cookie.name + "=" + cookie.value + "; "
        i += 1
                
    return string_cookies

def get_latam_cookies():
    url = 'https://www.latamairlines.com/cl/es/'
    response = requests.request("GET", url)
    cookies = response.cookies
    return cookies_to_string(cookies)
```

Now, this bunch of code returns the response headers from the requests I just did. It looks like this:

[image: request_cookies]

However, if I do this but with Selenium, I get a lot of more cookies:

```python
def get_latam_cookies_selenium():
   url = 'https://www.latamairlines.com/cl/es/'
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.get(url)
   cookies = driver.get_cookies()
   return cookies
```

The code above returns this:
[image: selenium_cookies]

I really need to get those cookies for other requests later. I think that this is what it's happening: With the requests method, I get the cookies from the response header of the requests (it makes sense). But, using Selenium, as I am simulating a web browser with the web driver, I get the cookies that the web page creates when someone (or in this case, a bot) enters to the web page for first time, and this cookies are automatically generated. SO MY QUESTION:

¿Is there a way I can get those cookies without using Selenium? Using Selenium is a solution, but it would take a very long time to do the web scrapping. If someone can help I would be very happy to read you answer!

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a `requests.Session()`

Here is an example:

```
import requests
import uuid

s = requests.Session()
headers =   {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.latamairlines.com/cl/es/'

resp = s.get(url,headers=headers)
print(s.cookies.get_dict())

origin = 'SCL'
dest = 'LRH'
leave = '2022-03-31'
back = '2022-03-01'

search = f'https://www.latamairlines.com/bff/air-offers/offers/search?origin={origin}&destination={dest}&inFrom={leave}&outFrom={back}&sort=RECOMMENDED&cabinType=Economy&inFlightDate=null&inOfferId=null&outFlightDate=null&outOfferId=null&adult=1&child=0&infant=0&redemption=false'
new_headers =   {
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36',
    'x-latam-app-session-id':str(uuid.uuid1()),
    'x-latam-application-country':'CL',
    'x-latam-application-lang':'es',
    'x-latam-application-name':'web-air-offers',
    'x-latam-application-oc':'cl',
    'x-latam-client-name':'web-air-offers',
    'x-latam-request-id': str(uuid.uuid1()),
    'x-latam-track-id':str(uuid.uuid1())
    }
data = s.get(search,headers=new_headers).json()
print(data)
```

Comment: Hi! I don't think that you understood me right, maybe I didn't explain me well. The cookies that I want to retrieve aren't the ones stored after the request stored in resp. (In fact are the same that I've shown in the first method). I want the bunch of cookies that Selenium returns to me, and I need to insert those cookies into the headers variable, the x-latam headers id doesn't need to be changed, I've already test them.

Comment: Olá Lucio! Eu também estou trabalhando em um projeto de scrapping para o LATAM Pass. Você quer unir os conhecimentos para conseguir resolver isso?